# Assigning node coordinates with cytoscape

Tags: graph, theory, cytoscape

I have a text file of 1000 points. There are 4 columns with 
["x" "y" "property 1" "property 2"]. Firstly I want to create nodes each with an (x,y) pair and I cannot find the proper way to do it in CYTOSCAPE. I then want to connect the nodes by providing a linking length I suppose (something that will give a reasonable physical meaning). Lastly I want to assign each node the property and derive some results (centralities). Please any insight on constructing the network would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: For your first task (create nodes each with an (x,y) pair) this is a basic feature of cytoscape. Have you tried setting your nodes' positions using the `node.position()` setter method? http://js.cytoscape.org/#node.position

Answer (score -1):

First, are you trying to do this with cytoscape.js or the desktop version of Cytoscape?  For the desktop version of Cytoscape, it's pretty easy to read in the data and map X and Y to the X and Y positions.  As was already mentioned you would use the node.position() method in cytoscape.js.

-- scooter

Comment: If it's easy, could you quickly say how this would be done?